# Multi Screen Support related Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

Project

-----Resources

------layout

-------layout-hdpi

--------layout-xhdpi -> It is working well for phones having resolution 720*800, etc.

---------layout-w1200dp -> When i run my application on real device or on emulator, ignores this folder and pick the xhdpi folder. I want to support the resolution such as 1920*1200.

**Note: Above folder are used to support Portrait mode**

Answer (score 0):

layout-xhdpi determines the density of pixels per inch and no resolution. For greater precision, use the xxxhdpi.
According to me, the target device is used to its maximum resolution automatically.
If you needed something else than clarify the question.

Comment: The DPI for the device with the resolution "1900*1200" is 320dpi i.e. xhdpi.

Comment: and therefore xhdpi directory is used and it's okay.

Comment: OK, But now in this situation how can i support tablets. Because the view is coming differently on phone and tablet even if they are of same DPI.

Comment: I do not know exactly what view you mean and how is different, but personally I recommend : Try create a small test application, where try different layout / view and test it on phone/tablet. Maybe you need to use a different layout to display a view correctly

Comment: I'm using custom font sizes and some fixed width and height. So, if i give margin according to 720*1280 resolution then this margin will look different on 1920*1200...... Yeah,i need different layout to display a view correctly that's why i created a specific folder layout-w1200dp specifically for the resolutions with width 1200 but this didn,t worked.....

Comment: I would try to use only one type of directories (not layout,layout-hdpi,layout-xhdpi...) and the system should choose the one that is closest to the device resolution :
layout-w800dp-land   /   

layout-w800dp-port   /   

layout-x1024dp-land   /   

layout-w1024dp-port    /   

layout-x1200dp-land   /   

layout-w1200dp-port    /

Comment: and check what directories was created in obj\debug\res\